# Entity Framework generates many to many tables with weird asian names and properties

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm currently working in a GIS project, I'm using ASP.NET MVC as platform and  Entity Framework (code-first) as ORM.

Everything was working just fine until I added the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` package to the solution so I can manipulate geometric data.

After building the project, the database was created successfully, but all the many-to-many tables were generated with weird names and properties (Asian chars)

[image: example of the many-to-many tables affected]

Comment: are you using entity framework code first?

Comment: yes i'm using entity framework code first

Comment: so are you sure there's no Unicode characters in your code?

Comment: i didn't catch exactly what you mean, my code was working perfectly until i added Microsoft.sqlserver.types. the strange thing is that i haven't found any one with this problem in the net ...